# How to delete Google search history

Tags: google-search, google-search-history

I forgot I was logged in with my school account which is hosted by Google.

How do I delete my search history?

Answer (score 1):

> The following answer **may not apply** for a  Google Apps for
>   Education account but only for a normal (consumer) Google account.

---

There are different ways to do this depending on what you want to achieve.
For example you could:

- Delete items individually
- Delete related activity
- Delete activity using search & filters
- Delete activity from a certain day or time period
- Delete everything in My Activity
- Stop saving activity
- Stop saving activity **completely**
- Stop saving activity **temporarily**

As per the [Google help page](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/465):

> You can delete past searches, browsing history, and other activity
>   from your Google Account. You're in control of what's stored in [My
>   Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/), and you can stop saving
>   most activity at any time.

In your case, you should try to:

> Delete activity from a certain day or time period
>   To delete all activity from today, yesterday, or another day or date range:
>
> 1. Go to [My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/).

Remember: **You first need to sign in to your school's Google Account**.

> 2. On the "My Activity" banner, choose More (the three little dots on the top right corner) and then `Delete activity by`.

[image: My Activity more]

> 3. Choose the day or date range.

[image: My Activity by]

> 4. Select Delete.
> 5. Confirm your choice.

In any case in the future you should always remember to **not log-in your school account when you do not want your history recorded**.

---

If you just need to **browse without saving your history in the browser**, you can use the [Incognito Mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464) in Chrome or [Private Browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history) in Firefox.
**Keep in mind though** that neither deleting your history nor Private Browsing makes you anonymous on the Internet. Your Internet service provider, school, or the sites themselves can still track what pages you visit. Private Browsing also doesn't protect you from keyloggers or spyware that may be installed on your computer.

Comment: The Asker mentions an account hosted by the school, so I expect it's a Google Apps for Education account. The instructions for a normal (consumer) Google account may not be applicable.

Comment: @AlE. I think you are most likely right. If the user can further confirm that, we will have to disregard (delete) my answer.

Comment: Google Search is not part of Google Apps (either for Work or for Edu). Google Search is a consumer product. The only way for a Google Apps admin to view any accounts browsing history is to reset the password for that account and then login as them. This process would be visible to the user as their password would no longer work, and it's highly unlikely that an Admin has time to do this for each account they manage. Having said that, it's likely the school has other tools, outside of Google Apps, to monitor where students browse if the searching was done on the school's network.

Comment: @Folk If that is the case then my top edit should be removed. Furthermore, in my last paragraph "_...Your Internet service provider, school, or the sites themselves can still track what pages you visit..._"  I mention exactly your thoughts.

Comment: You are correct, sorry. That comment kind of ran away from me. :)